# Half gaussian distribution and 68–95–99.7 upper limits

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, mean, standard-deviation

What are the relation between mean and standard deviation with the 68–95–99.7% upper limits on a [half gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution)  ?

The problem is that if I want to compute that myself, I will be stuck with computing this integral : [image]
to be equal at my confidence limit.

I'm sure that was already computed but I did not find it. Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's got to be the same thing, i.e. 1, 2 and 3 $\sigma$s of Gaussian (not half Gaussian).

The half Gaussian is a like Gaussian folded in the middle, so the density of each point jumps by a factor of 2. Hence when you move 1 $\sigma$ (of Gaussian!) from 0, it's the same probability weight as if you moved left and right 1 $\sigma$ in Gaussian.

Comment: Ok thanks ! So then if I understand well it is $\sigma$, $2 \sigma$, $3 \sigma$ at thre right of 0, with $\sigma = \frac{\sqrt{variance}}{1-\frac{2}{\pi}}$
Can you confirm that I am right ?

Comment: sorry, with $\sigma =\sqrt{ \frac{variance}{1-\frac{2}{\pi}}}$

Comment: I clarified the answer